# Visual Studio 2013 not finding code after I moved it to another file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

All my code was in one file, say, Form1.cs. The file was getting too big so I decided to break up my code into several new files. I used the solution explorer to add the new files. (right-click > Add > New Item... > Code File)

So for example, I created SomeFolder/ClickHandlers.cs, and cut my someButton_Click() function from Form1.cs and pasted it into said new file. So the new file looks like this:

```
using blah;
using blah...;

namespace FooApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        void someButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Do things..
        }
    }
}
```

And Form1.cs no longer has this function in it. My program runs perfectly fine. But VS didn't seem to get the memo. When I go into the designer, select "someButton" and then go into the events list in the Properties Pane, I see my function "someButton_Click" in the Click event. When I double-click the function, it takes me to the beginning(ish) of Form1.cs, not into SomeFolder/ClickHandlers.cs where the function got moved to.

How can I make VS learn the new locations of my code so I can be taken to it from the designer? I've tried deleting the .suo file and the obj folder. No dice.

Comment: check namespace of moved files

Comment: @h.o.m.a.n, thanks. The namespace in the new file matches that of the file that the code was moved from.

Comment: So your new file holds a different class, right?  You can't just move a form event handler into a different class.  If you tried to put the same class name, same namespace, in two different files, then I'd think the project wouldn't compile.  When the file holding the form class gets too large, then I try to separate the code by functionality into a new class in a new file.  In other words, I leave the code that relates to the form in the form class, but put the "business" (aka problem domain) logic in the new class.  Typically form class event handlers call methods in the new class.

Comment: As I see it he simply added another file that defines the same partial class. That's why compilation works. I'd guess that if you'd call a method in that file somewhere else in the code and navigated there by right click it would work.

The issue is likely with the WinForms designer always expecting user code to be in the Non-Designer file named like the class which is why it switches to that file and then stumbles when it can't find the method.

It's visible in the designer as that uses the AST created for Intelisense. I don't think you can change that behavior however.

Comment: @Oliver Ulm, that's correct. Same partial class.